# Display equations in tabularx

Tags: tabularx, displaystyle

Why the first MWE works and second not?
First MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=3mm,preview]{standalone}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{tabularx,graphicx}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{\hsize}{m{0.4\hsize}X}
\includegraphics[width=0.9\hsize]{example-image}
    &
\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
\delta_h(t) = \begin{dcases}
                \frac{1}{2h}    &\text{pri}\quad -h<t<h \\
                    0           &\text{sicer}
              \end{dcases}
\end{equation}
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{document}
```

second MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=3mm,preview]{standalone}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{tabularx,graphicx}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{\hsize}{m{0.4\hsize}X}
\includegraphics[width=0.9\hsize]{example-image}
    &
\begin{gather}\label{eq:1}
\delta_h(t) = \begin{dcases}
                \frac{1}{2h}    &\text{pri}\quad -h<t<h \\
                    0           &\text{sicer}
              \end{dcases}
\end{gather}
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{document}
```

Second MWE gives error `Forbidden control sequences found while scanning of \gather.` The same error appear if the equations is in `align` environment. This error persist even if I use in cell with equations `minipage`.

It seems that there is some mismatch with use of `\\` in `amsmath` environments in `tabularx` cells type `X` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an extra pair of braces to enclose the `dcases` (which is basically an `array`):

```
\begin{tabularx}{\hsize}{m{0.4\hsize}X}
\includegraphics[width=0.9\hsize]{example-image}
    &
\begin{gather}\label{eq:1}
{\delta_h(t) = \begin{dcases}
                \frac{1}{2h}    &\text{pri}\quad -h<t<h \\
                    0           &\text{sicer}
              \end{dcases}}
\end{gather}
\end{tabularx}
```

The complte code, with some modifications (see Remarks below):

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=3mm,preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tabularx,graphicx}

\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\hsize}{m{0.4\hsize}X}
\includegraphics[width=0.9\hsize]{example-image}
    &
\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
{\delta_h(t) = \begin{dcases}
                \frac{1}{2h}    &\text{pri}\quad -h<t<h \\
                    0           &\text{sicer}
              \end{dcases}}
\end{equation}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Remarks

- It is unclear to me why use a `dcases` inside a `gather`. The `gather` environment is designed for a *group* of consecutive equations for which there is no alignment desired among them and a dcases structure is (from the logical point of view) just one unit. An `equation` environment seems to be the natural choice.
- I used

  ```
  \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
  ```

  to get the image and the equation vertically aligned at the center.

Comment: @GonzalesMedina. Thank you for answer. Environment `gather` is used only to show, that `dcases` work differently in `equation` as in `gather`. This show, that `equation` is more robust than other `amsmath` environments. Of course, in showed example I use `equation`. Let me emphasize, that any construct with multi line equation with `gather`, `align` gives the same error.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is the unprotected `\\` of `dcases` inside a `tabular`-related environment. The following non-[`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) MWE replicates the problem (using `p`-columns; a toned-down version of `tabularx`'s `X`-columns):

```
%\documentclass[12pt,border=3mm,preview]{standalone}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{0.4\linewidth}p{0.5\linewidth}}
  \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image}
    &
    \begin{gather}\label{eq:1}
    \delta_h(t) = \begin{dcases}
                    \frac{1}{2h}    &\text{pri}\quad -h<t<h \\
                        0           &\text{sicer}
                  \end{dcases}
    \end{gather}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

For this I would use a set of `minipage`s rather than a `tabularx` as well as an `equation` instead of `gather`:

[image]

```
%\documentclass[12pt,border=3mm,preview]{standalone}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{.4\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.6\linewidth}
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:1}
  \delta_h(t) = \begin{dcases}
                  \frac{1}{2h} & \text{pri}\quad -h<t<h \\
                      0        & \text{sicer}
                \end{dcases}
  \end{equation}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

`minipage`s necessarily have their anchor points at the vertical centre.

Comment: in similar simple cases I actually use minipages', but I wonder, whay tis not work in `X˙column type. It is based on `parbox` with width calculated by `tabularx` algorithm, isn't it?

Comment: your example with `tabular` with `p{...}` type of column is nice workaround, however why this work and with `X` in `tabularx` not, is still open questions. It seems, that `amsmath` math environments doesn't isolate `\\` from `X` cell as `equation` does. Is this some kind of bug?