# Tabularx misconfiguration with equations

Tags: equations, tabularx

I am trying to make a table like this:

[image]

I am using tabularx for creating it, here is the code:

```
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\newcommand\fch{0.2}
\newcommand\sch{0.35}
\newcommand\tch{0.3}
\newcommand\fich{0.15}
\begin{tabularx}{\hsize}{|C{\fch}|C{\sch}|C{\tch}|C{\fich}|}
\caption{Calculation, description and reference of the extracted acoustical features.}
\label{acoustic_table} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Acoustic Indices}} \\ \hline
 \textbf{Acoustic Feature}&  \textbf{Calculation}&  \textbf{Description}&  \textbf{Reference}\\ \hline
Acoustic Complexity Index (frequency-time) ($ACIf_t$) &\vbox{\begin{equation}  \sum_{i=1}^{N_t}  \sum_{j=1}^{N_{f-1}} \frac{|I_{i,j}-I_{i,j+1}|}{I_{i,j}+I_{i,j+1}} \end{equation}}   & Where $I_{i,j}$ is the normalized amplitude of each pulse in the time step i and frequency bin j, $N_t$ is the number of temporal steps and $N_f$ is the number of frequency bins in the spectrogram. $ACIf_t$ measures the information in two successive frequency bins along each time step. & \cite{Farina2016}\\ \hline
$ACIf_t$ evenness ($ACIf_{te}$) & \vbox{\begin{equation}  \frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^{N_t}{\sum_{j=1}^{N_{f-1}} \frac{|I_{i,j}-I_{i,j+1}|}{I_{i,j}+I_{i,j+1}}}^{2}} \end{equation}}  & Levins evenness applied to the $ACIf_t$. $ACIf_{te}$ measures the distribution of intensity along each time step.  & \cite{Farina2016} \\ \hline
 &  &  &  \\ \hline
 &  &  &  \\ \hline
 &  &  &  \\ \hline
 &  &  &  \\ \hline
 &  &  &  \\ \hline
 &  &  &  \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{} &  & \multirow{2}{*}{} & \multirow{2}{*}{} \\ \cline{2-2}
 &  &  &  \\ \hline
 &  &  &  \\ \hline
 &  &  &  \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{} &  & \multirow{2}{*}{} & \multirow{2}{*}{} \\ \cline{2-2}
 &  &  &  \\ \hline
 &  &  &  \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{} &  & \multirow{2}{*}{} & \multirow{2}{*}{} \\ \cline{2-2}
 &  &  &  \\ \hline
 &  &  &  \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{} &  & \multirow{2}{*}{} & \multirow{2}{*}{} \\ \cline{2-2}
 &  &  &  \\ \hline
 &  &  &  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{} \\ \hline
 &  &  &  \\ \hline
 &  &  &  \\ \hline
 &  &  &  \\ \hline
 &  &  &  \\ \hline
 &  &  &  \\ \hline
 &  &  &  \\ \hline
 &  &  &  \\ \hline
 &  &  &  \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
```

Which gives me:

[image]

But I want to use parenthesis for the second equation, as the first image shows. When I add the parenthesis to that part, I get this:

[image]

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).  While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  Also, the solution may be dependent on the packages that you are using.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it using gather for the second equation and adding another pair of braces as indicated in [Display equations in tabularx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256507/display-equations-in-tabularx) . Although the numbering was not well aligned.

[image]

I am sorry I didn't make it clearer

Answer (score 2):

- you not provide complete small document, so your document layout is unknown, consequently is not known if you have enough space for your table
- caption had not to be inside `tabularx` environment (or do you use `ltablex`? this is not clear from your question). i comment it.
- using own preamble and adding parenthesis as you wish i can't reproduce your problem:

[image]

used code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\newcommand\fch{0.2}
\newcommand\sch{0.35}
\newcommand\tch{0.3}
\newcommand\fich{0.15}
\begin{tabularx}{\hsize}{|C{\fch}|C{\sch}|C{\tch}|C{\fich}|}
%\caption{Calculation, description and reference of the extracted acoustical features.}
%\label{acoustic_table} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Acoustic Indices}} \\ \hline
 \textbf{Acoustic Feature}
    &  \textbf{Calculation}
        &  \textbf{Description}
            &  \textbf{Reference}\\ \hline
Acoustic Complexity Index (frequency-time) ($ACIf_t$)
    &\vbox{\begin{equation}
    \sum_{i=1}^{N_t}  \sum_{j=1}^{N_{f-1}} \frac{|I_{i,j}-I_{i,j+1}|}{I_{i,j}+I_{i,j+1}}
    \end{equation}}
        & Where $I_{i,j}$ is the normalized amplitude of each pulse in the time step i and frequency bin j, $N_t$ is the number of temporal steps and $N_f$ is the number of frequency bins in the spectrogram. $ACIf_t$ measures the information in two successive frequency bins along each time step.
            & \cite{Farina2016} \\ \hline
$ACIf_t$ evenness ($ACIf_{te}$)
    & \vbox{\begin{equation}
    \frac{1}
         {\displaystyle
          \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N_t}
            \left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^{N_{f-1}}
                \dfrac{|I_{i,j}-I_{i,j+1}|}
                       {I_{i,j}+I_{i,j+1}}
            \right)^2
          }
    \end{equation}}
        & Levins evenness applied to the $ACIf_t$. $ACIf_{te}$ measures the distribution of intensity along each time step.
            & \cite{Farina2016} \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```